# How to correctly reload a specific iptables rule

Tags: iptables

My iptables script contains many rules. Every time it runs, it flushes the old rules and reloads them so they don't stack. But since it takes a long time to run, I want to create a separate script to run only this rule.

```
   myacl=$(cat list.txt)
   for string in `echo -e "$myacl"`; do
     iptables -A FORWARD -m string --string "$string" --algo bm -j DROP
   done
```

So, what I need is to reload this rule, so that it takes the changes I made in "list.txt", but does not affect the rest of the iptables rules, which in another script were already loaded and running.

PD: someone [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10197461/8747573) says that with "iptables -D". Example:

```
    myacl=$(cat list.txt)
    for string in `echo -e "$myacl"`; do
       iptables -D FORWARD -m string --string "$string" --algo bm -j DROP
       iptables -A FORWARD -m string --string "$string" --algo bm -j DROP
    done
```

But this solution I don't think will work and it is strange to me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The linux kernel rules are modified by the iptables command. If you flush all the rules and recreate them, there is a little time where there is no rule at all (and all the packets my be dropped). It is the principle of "reload" or "restart".

Use the -D (Delete) will only delete one rule. The -A will Append at the end the new rule. The others ones are not touched.

I don't understand your script : you remove a rule to re-add it at the end. If you have changed your file since the last time you run the script, you will not remove all the existing rules (it they doesn't exists anymore in your file) as iptables will not found them.

Example :

- First step : your file has "string1 string2 string3"
- Run it, the kernel will have 3 rules : "string1", "string2" and "string3". There will be errors if the rules doesn't exists to deletion.
- Second step : update the file to "string1 string3 string4"
- Run the script. The kernel will never remove the "string2", as it doesn't exists in the file (the rule will be kept active), and you will have an error when you will try to remove the "string4" as it doesn't exists yet.

Comment: Thank you, but it is not very clear to me. I have modified the content of the question, so that it is understood exactly what I want to do

Comment: You may need two files : one with the rules to delete and one with the rules to add.